# Под знанием XML что обычно подрзумевают?

Tags: xml

Под знанием XML что обычно подрзумевают?

Comment: Вопросы уровня "что подразумевается под..." нужно задавать тому, кто подразумевает. Хотя бы потому, что у него может быть своё понимание, никак не связанное с тем, что могут ответить здесь.

Comment: Я подразумевал требования работодателя.Мое упущение, не указал контекст.

Comment: @alex91 Был задан вопрос "Под знанием XML что обычно подразумевают?". Нормальная интерпретация -- вопрошающий интересуется опытом других, которые участвовали в собеседовании и т.п. с той или другой стороны. Как его понял @klopp, мне уже стало интересно.

Comment: Я так думаю: если ты сам себе можешь ответить знаешь ли  XYZ, то и с рабоьтодателем поглворишь :) А с той стороны, наверное, лучше давать тестовые задания.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знание стандарта XML и работа с ним. Допустим PHP программист может работать XML на библиотеке SimpleXML или же DomDocument.

Comment: А,Вы подтвердили мое предположение,нужно уметь с ним взаимодействовать.
Просто были еще варианты,бредовые,но они отпали.